# Pass the values from a post method via routes using mvc style

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

When sending a post form with username and password, I'm getting an error saying: `Cannot POST /validateUser`

My form looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Login Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="contentDiv">
        <form action="/validateUser" method="post">
        <!-- user input-->
        Username:<br>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required><br><br>
        Password:<br>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required><br><br>
        
        <input type="submit" value="login">
        </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In my app.js I have this

```
const express = require('express'),
app = express(),

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

/*For getting form input*/
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const validationRoute = require('./routes/validationRoute')

/* Routes */
//app.post('/validateUser', validationRoute)
app.use('/validateUser', validationRoute)

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on Port: ${PORT}`);
})
```

My validationRoute looks like this (Though it seems we never get this far, since the error is in app.js)

```
const express = require('express'),
router = express.Router(),
validationCon = require('../controllers/validationController')

router.get('/', validationCon.validateUser);

/*
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log("URL from validate: "+req.url)
}) */

module.exports = router;
```

And my validationController looks like this (Though it seems we never get this far, since the error is in app.js)

```
const { logic } = require("../dbLogic");

module.exports = {

    validateUser: async (req, res) => {
        const uName = req.uName, 
            pwd = req.pwd;
        const success = true//await logic.validateUser(uName, pwd);

        if(success) {
            //res.status(201).send('Login accepted');
            res.render('../views/pages/secret');
        }
        else
            res.status(400).send("Bad confidentials");
    }
}
```

Important info!!!

Instead of doing: `app.use('/validateUser', validationRoute)`

If do

```
app.use('/validateUser', function (req, res)  {
    const name = req.body.username

    console.log(name)
})
```

then it works nicely, I am able to access the username and password. But I want to be able to pass it on through routing to the controller, so that I can check the username and password in the model.

Can anyone see what's wrong with this: `app.use('/validateUser', validationRoute)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `POST` request handler to the `validationRoute` router:

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log("URL from validate: "+req.url, ' req.body: ', req.body)
})
```

It gives error because there is no `POST` handler in the router, for any type of HTTP request. Adding `router.use` would also work, the same as it worked with `app.use` in your attempt.

Read more:

> Using middleware
>
> https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html